# Why do I need to add a namespace in the XML when using <xs:attribute ref="..."/> in the XSD?

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-namespaces, xsd-validation

I just learned about the possiblity of defining an attribute type and referencing it from different places in my XSD. What I do not understand: This modelling changes how the attribute needs to be written in the XML file and I don't see why.

Here I have a small example.
My XSD looks like this:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ns="http://mynamespace" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://mynamespace" version="1.0">
  <xs:element name="Shape">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="type" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="color" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute ref="ns:color2"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  <xs:attribute name="color2" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:schema>
```

As you can see, there are two different variants of modelling a string attribute for my shape-element. I would expect that both can be used the same way in an XML validating this XSD. But in order to fulfill the validation, I need to add a namespace in front of the color2 attribute:

```
<Shape xmlns:ns="http://mynamespace" xmlns="http://mynamespace" color="test" ns:color2="test">
    <type>circle</type>
</Shape>
```

Of course, I could add "ns:" in front of "color", too. But for color it is optional. Only for color2 it is required and my validation fails if I omit the namespace. So, why is there a difference between color and color2 in my XML?